# Approval process not assgining to correct approver , Approval process not working as expexted!

Tags: quote, approval-process, quotelineitem, approval-step

if Discount 0 to <=5 area manager

if Discount 5> to <=10 sales manager

if Discount 10> CEO

i have two fields on the  user object
area manager & sales manager(i will assigin this two fields when new user record created)
&

i have two fields on the quote object,
area manager & sales manager(i will query user and assigin based on the quote owner(userid) and assigne them in using trigger)

so as above three condition it should get assgined to respected managers.

now i have two fields, discount and is Discount approval needed? 
in my approval process should start run when

1)discount > 0 & is Discount approval needed =true
entry criteria
[image]

steps:

[image]
what i am doing here can anyone suggest here to fix this.

it's assgining fine for the area manager(when my quote discount between 0% to 5%) but not showing for in his home tab when he login, it's showing approve/reject links when he goto that opportunity->quote.

it's not assigning to the sales manager(when my quote discount between 5 to 10).
the problem facing here is it's auto approving the quote approval with quote owner name.

Comment: your first approval step if discount GT 5, it approves hence 2nd and 3rd approval step never get executed

Comment: Why? And Any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your condition first else is "Approve" so it wont execute 2nd and 3rd step

Your approval Steps should be like this :

```
step 1 : check if its >10 then send to manager else "next step".
step 2 : check if >5 and <10 then send it to sales manager else "next step".
step 3 : check if its >0 and <5 then send it to area manager else "approve".
```

Thank you

Comment: Thank you Sir, it's assgining now to the correct approver.<3